# R plotly - display image on hover in a map

Tags: javascript, r, plotly, interactive

I'm following these 2 great examples for how to display an image when hovering over a point in R plotly: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601216/r-plotly-display-image-on-hover) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77041016/showing-images-on-hover-in-plotly-r). I'm able to make them work just fine, until I make the plot into a map. Then the approach breaks. Could anyone help modify it to work with a plotly map?

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(x = c(-81.026, -81.025, -81.028), y = c(44.13, 44.14, 44.15), 
     url = c("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Beethoven.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Croce-Mozart-Detail.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg"))

d3 <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "d3", "7.3",
  src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/"),
  script = "d3.min.js"
)

js <- '
function(el) {
  var tooltip = d3.select("#" + el.id + " .svg-container")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "my-custom-tooltip");

  el.on("plotly_hover", function(d) {
    var pt = d.points[0];
    var x = pt.xaxis.range[0];
    var y = pt.yaxis.range[1];
    var xPixel = pt.xaxis.l2p(x) + pt.xaxis._offset;
    var yPixel = pt.yaxis.l2p(y) + pt.yaxis._offset;
    var img = "<img src=\\\"" +  pt.customdata + "\\\" width=100>";
    tooltip.html(img)
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("left", xPixel + "px")
      .style("top", yPixel + "px");
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(300)
      .style("opacity", 1);
  });

  el.on("plotly_unhover", function(d) {
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  });
}
'
```

This works and displays an image on hover

```
p <-plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", hoverinfo = ~x, customdata = ~url) %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender(js)

p$dependencies <- c(p$dependencies, list(d3))
p
```

This does not...

```
p <- plot_ly(df, lon = ~x, lat = ~y, type = "scattermapbox", mode = "markers", hoverinfo = ~x, customdata = ~url) %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                      center = list(lon = -81 ,lat= 44),
                      layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                         source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender(js)

p$dependencies <- c(p$dependencies, list(d3))
p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is the structure of Plotly changes significantly with maps. While the idea of x and y axes is obviously still present, Plotly does not associate axes with maps.

I've provided 2 solutions for you. The first is basically an adaptation of the original `onRender`. The second modifies it a bit more.

In the original format, when you zoom into the plot/map, the image moves out of viewable space. With the second option, it will look the same as the first plot if you don't zoom. If you zoom in, you'll see that the image remains visible regardless of the zoom position.

The first adaptation of the object `js`

```
js <- '
function(el) {
  var tooltip = d3.select("#" + el.id + " .svg-container")  /* identify container */
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "my-custom-tooltip");

  el.on("plotly_hover", function(d) {                     /* add content on hover */ 
      pt = d.points[0];
      img = "<img src=\\\"" + pt.customdata + "\\\" width=100>";  /* image in hover */ 
                                        /* the position of the map on the webpage */ 
      bx = document.querySelector("div.mapboxgl-map").getBoundingClientRect();
      tooltip.html(img)
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("left", bx.left + "px") /* assign left and top to match map position*/
        .style("top", bx.top + "px");
      tooltip.transition()         
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 1);
  })
  el.on("plotly_unhover", function(d) {  /* collapse image when tooltip collapses */
      tooltip.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  });
}
'
```

[image]

The second adaptation of the object `js`, so the image is viewable when zooming/panning, etc.

```
js2 <- '
function(el) {
  var tooltip = d3.select("#" + el.id + " .svg-container")  /* identify container */
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "my-custom-tooltip");

  el.on("plotly_hover", function(d) {                     /* add content on hover */ 
      pt = d.points[0];
      console.log(pt);
      img = "<img src=\\\"" +  pt.customdata + "\\\" width=100>";  /* image in hover */ 
                                        /* the position of the map on the webpage */ 
      bx = document.querySelector("div.mapboxgl-map").getBoundingClientRect();
      var h = window.innerHeight;       /* get viewers screen size */
      var w = window.innerWidth;
      tooltip.html(img)             /* calculate % left/right map to screen position */
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("left", (bx.left/w * 100) + "vw")
        .style("top", (bx.top/h * 100) + "vh");
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 1);
  })
  el.on("plotly_unhover", function(d) {  /* collapse image when tooltip collapses */
      tooltip.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  });
}
'
```

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is brilliant. And the second time you pointed out to me (with much patience) that maps don't have axes in plotly.  Is there a way to allow the images to appear on hover only for one set of markers? In my plot, I have 3 layers of markers, and I only want the images to show up for one. So the other 2 display a broken image link on hover... I can probably find a link to an empty, transparent image if I needed to, but maybe there's a cleaner solution?

Comment: Yes, as this is setup to use `customdata`, just make sure that the line items that do not coincide with a picture are `""` instead of a URL or an encoded image. If you run into any problems, let me know.

Comment: Got it. I use several different data sources, so I just created empty fields in those and added the `customdata`. Huge thanks! A couple of follow-up questions (and I'm happy to make a new question for those!) 1) I can't quite figure out how the size of the image is set? and 2) is there a way to have the image at the tooltip / with the hovertext, rather than in the corner?

Comment: In the 2nd option, I've used `vh` and `vw` in the JS -- this is a dynamic measurement based on percentages. 100 is 100% of the viewable width or height (whether vw or vh respectively). If you wanted it to be 10% wider, you could modify`(bx.left/w * 100)` to `(bx.left/w * 100) * 1.1`.  As far as images within the tooltip-- YES, you can do that, too. But you'll likely need to be more specific. [Here's an example of images in a tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73280006/tooltip-inserting-image-and-or-ggplot-in-plotly-r/73300702#73300702). Next question? :)

Comment: Always more questions :D I tried the multiplication approach before posting the comment - it seemed to have just moved the image 10% off to the right (using the 1.1 multiplier) as opposed to making it 10% wider. Then I ran out of numbers that were obviously futz-able and posted the comment... I'd be happy to post a new question though if you'd prefer!

Comment: That's an EPIC FAIL on my part. If you want to change the image size, forget what I said in my last comment...instead (for real this time...) in the JS, where `img` is defined you set the size. (`img = "<img src=\\\"" +  pt.customdata + "\\\" width=100>";`). That 100 is 100px. If you want to make it bigger, change this number (e.g., `img = "<img src=\\\"" +  pt.customdata + "\\\" width=150>";`). Currently, the image aspect ratio is locked. So you only change the width to change both height and width proportionately.

Comment: Ha, I missed THAT number to futz with. Thank you!!! Would you be up for taking a look at this? And HUGE thank you for seemingly single-handedly resolving all my issues with `plotly`... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76909502/r-mapbox-plotly-with-animation-and-a-shapefile

Comment: Answered....next question??

Comment: Care to take a stab at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77239759/image-on-hover-and-video-on-click-r-plotly