# Image on hover and video on click - R plotly

Tags: javascript, r, plotly, interactive

I have a plotly map with 2 traces. I would like to show images on hover for trace 1, and video on click for trace 2. The hovering works great thanks to the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145055/r-plotly-display-image-on-hover-in-a-map). For the video, I used the approach described [here](https://plotly-r.com/supplying-custom-data). It somewhat works.

The upgrades I am interested in are:

1. How do I make the on-click video to only work for trace 2? So that clicking on trace 1 doesn't do anything?
2. How do I make the video be smaller and show up within the map area, as opposed to below the map?
3. How do I make the video close-able? Currently I can't make it go away, unless I click on trace 1
   4
4. The map seems to no longer be zoomable after this exercise...

Huge thanks for any thoughts!

Toy example below. Data, functions, and JS bits:

````
```{r}

library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

df <- data.frame(x = c(-81.026, -81.025, -81.028), y = c(44.13, 44.14, 44.15), 
     url = c("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Beethoven.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Croce-Mozart-Detail.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg"))

d3 <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "d3", "7.3",
  src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/"),
  script = "d3.min.js"
)

js2 <- '
function(el) {
  var tooltip = d3.select("#" + el.id + " .svg-container")  /* identify container */
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "my-custom-tooltip");

  el.on("plotly_hover", function(d) {                     /* add content on hover */ 
      pt = d.points[0];
      console.log(pt);
      img = "<img src=\\\"" +  pt.customdata + "\\\" width=100>";  /* image in hover */ 
                                        /* the position of the map on the webpage */ 
      bx = document.querySelector("div.mapboxgl-map").getBoundingClientRect();
      var h = window.innerHeight;       /* get viewers screen size */
      var w = window.innerWidth;
      tooltip.html(img)             /* calculate % left/right map to screen position */
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("left", (bx.left/w * 100) + "vw")
        .style("top", (bx.top/h * 100) + "vh");
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 1);
  })
  el.on("plotly_unhover", function(d) {  /* collapse image when tooltip collapses */
      tooltip.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  });
}
'

js3 <- "function(el) { 
           var container = document.getElementById('video');
           el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
             var url = d.points[0].customdata;
             renderReactPlayer(container, {url: url, playing: true});
           })
        }"    

react_player <- runpkg::download_files(
      "react-player", 
      "dist/ReactPlayer.standalone.js"
    )


```
````

Plot:

````
 ```{r}
 video <- tags$div(id = "video", align = "center")

 p <- plot_ly(df, lon = ~x, lat = ~y, type = "scattermapbox", mode = "markers", hoverinfo = ~x, customdata = ~url) %>%
    add_trace(data = df, lon = ~x + 0.1, lat = ~y, type = "scattermapbox", mode = "markers", hoverinfo = ~x, customdata = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ab_channel=RickAstley") %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                      center = list(lon = -81 ,lat= 44),
                      layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                         source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) %>%
  onRender(js2) %>%
  onRender(js3) 

p$dependencies <- c(p$dependencies, list(d3))
p


# create the HTML page
browsable(tagList(p, video, react_player))

```
````

**EDIT**

The entire code, put together using the fixes in the answer. Shows a broken video link when hovering over the trace 1 points...

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

df <- data.frame(x = c(-81.026, -81.025, -81.028), y = c(44.13, 44.14, 44.15), 
     url = c("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Beethoven.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Croce-Mozart-Detail.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg"))

d3 <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "d3", "7.3",
  src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/"),
  script = "d3.min.js"
)

js2 <- '
function(el) {
  var tooltip = d3.select("#" + el.id + " .svg-container")  /* identify container */
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "my-custom-tooltip");

  el.on("plotly_hover", function(d) {                     /* add content on hover */ 
      pt = d.points[0];
      console.log(pt);
      img = "<img src=\\\"" +  pt.customdata + "\\\" width=100>";  /* image in hover */ 
                                        /* the position of the map on the webpage */ 
      bx = document.querySelector("div.mapboxgl-map").getBoundingClientRect();
      var h = window.innerHeight;       /* get viewers screen size */
      var w = window.innerWidth;
      tooltip.html(img)             /* calculate % left/right map to screen position */
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("left", (bx.left/w * 100) + "vw")
        .style("top", (bx.top/h * 100) + "vh");
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 1);
  })
  el.on("plotly_unhover", function(d) {  /* collapse image when tooltip collapses */
      tooltip.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  });
}
'

# replacement of `js3`, most mods are taken from `js2`
js3N <- "function(el) {
            $('head').append('<style>iframe[id^=\"widget\"] { width: 100%; } </style>');
            var container = document.getElementById('video');
            el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
                url = d.points[0].customdata;             /* changed to global (removed var) */
                var h = window.innerHeight;
                var w = window.innerWidth;
                container.setAttribute(     /* calculate % left/right map to screen position */
                  'style',
                  'position: absolute; left:' + (bx.left/w * 100) + 'vw; ' +
                  'top: ' + (bx.top/h * 100) + 'vh;');
                $('[id^=widget]').css('opacity', 1);  /* opac = 0 stop video; opac = 1 play */
                renderReactPlayer(container, {url: url, playing: true});
            })
            el.on('plotly_doubleclick', function(d) {  /* collapse image when container collapses */
                renderReactPlayer($('#video')[0], {url: url, playing: false});  /* stop video */
                $('[id^=widget]').css('opacity', 0);  /* hide video */
            });
        }" 

# replacement of `video` -- removed align = "center"
video <- tags$div(id = "video")
react_player <- runpkg::download_files(
      "react-player", 
      "dist/ReactPlayer.standalone.js"
    )


p <- plot_ly(df, lon = ~x, lat = ~y, type = "scattermapbox", mode = "markers", 
             hoverinfo = ~x, customdata = ~url) %>%
  add_trace(data = df, lon = ~x + 0.1, lat = ~y, type = "scattermapbox", 
            mode = "markers", hoverinfo = ~x, 
            customdata = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ab_channel=RickAstley") %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                       center = list(lon = -81 ,lat= 44),
                       layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                          source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) %>%
  onRender(js2) %>%
  # onRender(js3)
  onRender(js3N) %>% 
  config(doubleClickDelay = 1500)    #<---- I'm new!!

p$dependencies <- c(p$dependencies, list(d3))

# create the HTML page
browsable(tagList(p, video, react_player))
```

**EDIT 2**
This is the Rmd file as I have it together:

````
```{r, warning=FALSE, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}

library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

df <- data.frame(x = c(-81.026, -81.025, -81.028), y = c(44.13, 44.14, 44.15), 
     url = c("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Beethoven.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Croce-Mozart-Detail.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg"))

d3 <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "d3", "7.3",
  src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/"),
  script = "d3.min.js"
)

jsC <- "
function(el) {
    var tooltip = d3.select('#' + el.id + ' .svg-container')  /* identify container */
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'my-custom-tooltip');
    $('head').append('<style>iframe[id^=\"widget\"] { width: 100%; } </style>');
    var container = document.getElementById('video');

    el.on('plotly_hover', function(d) {         /* add content on hover */ 
        pt = d.points[0];
        var h = window.innerHeight;             /* get viewers screen size */
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        bx = document.querySelector('div.mapboxgl-map').getBoundingClientRect();

        if(pt.curveNumber === 0) {              /* you have an image; first trace */
                  /* if hovering on point that contains an image, halt/hide video - playing */
            if($('[id^=widget]').length) {
                renderReactPlayer($('#video')[0], {url: pt.customdata, playing: false});  /* stop video */
                $('[id^=widget]').css('opacity', 0);  /* hide video */
            }
            img = '<img src=\\\'' +  pt.customdata + '\\\' width=100>';  /* image in hover */ 
                        /* the position of the map on the webpage */ 
            tooltip.html(img)             /* calculate % left/right map to screen position */
                .style('position', 'absolute')
                .style('left', (bx.left/w * 100) + 'vw')
                .style('top', (bx.top/h * 100) + 'vh');
            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(300)
                .style('opacity', 1);


        } else if (pt.curveNumber === 1) {     /* you have a video; second trace */
              container.setAttribute(     /* calculate % left/right map to screen position */
                  'style',
                  'position: absolute; left:' + (bx.left/w * 100) + 'vw; ' +
                  'top: ' + (bx.top/h * 100) + 'vh;');
              $('[id^=widget]').css('opacity', 1);  /* opac = 0 stop video; opac = 1 play */
              renderReactPlayer(container, {url: pt.customdata, playing: true});
        }
    });
    el.on('plotly_unhover', function(d) {  /* collapse image when tooltip collapses */
        tooltip.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style('opacity', 0);
    });
    el.on('plotly_doubleclick', function(d) {  /* collapse image when container collapses */
        renderReactPlayer($('#video')[0], {url: pt.customdata, playing: false});  /* stop video */
        $('[id^=widget]').css('opacity', 0);  /* hide video */
    });
}"

# replacement of `video` -- removed align = "center"
video <- tags$div(id = "video")
react_player <- runpkg::download_files(
      "react-player", 
      "dist/ReactPlayer.standalone.js"
    )


p <- plot_ly(df, lon = ~x, lat = ~y, type = "scattermapbox", mode = "markers", 
             hoverinfo = ~x, customdata = ~url) %>%
  add_trace(data = df, lon = ~x + 0.1, lat = ~y, type = "scattermapbox", 
            mode = "markers", hoverinfo = ~x, 
            customdata = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-RkqON3oVM") %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                       center = list(lon = -81 ,lat= 44),
                       layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                          source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) %>%
  #onRender(js2) %>%
  # onRender(js3)
  #onRender(js3N) %>% 
  onRender(jsC) %>%            #<---- I'm new!!
  config(doubleClickDelay = 1500)    #<---- I'm new!!

p$dependencies <- c(p$dependencies, list(d3))

# create the HTML page
browsable(tagList(p, video, react_player))

```
````

Answer (score 1):

##### Another Update

I was finally able to replicate the issue you're having with the zoom.

I've made a few changes in the code for `jsC`.

- Another style added to the head for the class `.hideMe` and its children.
- Instead of calling for the opacity to change regarding the video element, now the code adds or removes the class `hideMe` to the parent container of the video.

```
jsC = "
function(el) {
    var tooltip = d3.select('#' + el.id + ' .svg-container')  /* identify container */
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'my-custom-tooltip');
    $('head').append('<style>iframe[id^=\"widget\"] { width: 100%; } .hideMe, .hideMe div, .hideMe iframe { width: 0 !important; } </style>');
    var container = document.getElementById('video');

    el.on('plotly_hover', function(d) {         /* add content on hover */ 
        pt = d.points[0];
        var h = window.innerHeight;             /* get viewers screen size */
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        bx = document.querySelector('div.mapboxgl-map').getBoundingClientRect();

        if(pt.curveNumber === 0) {              /* you have an image; first trace */
                  /* if hovering on point that contains an image, halt/hide video - playing */
            if($('[id^=widget]').length) {
                renderReactPlayer($('#video')[0], {url: pt.customdata, playing: false});  /* stop video */
                $('#video').addClass('hideMe');      /* hide video */
            }
            img = '<img src=\\\'' +  pt.customdata + '\\\' width=100>';  /* image in hover */ 
                        /* the position of the map on the webpage */ 
            tooltip.html(img)             /* calculate % left/right map to screen position */
                .style('position', 'absolute')
                .style('left', (bx.left/w * 100) + 'vw')
                .style('top', (bx.top/h * 100) + 'vh');
            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(300)
                .style('opacity', 1);


        } else if (pt.curveNumber === 1) {     /* you have a video; second trace */
              container.setAttribute(     /* calculate % left/right map to screen position */
                  'style',
                  'position: absolute; left:' + (bx.left/w * 100) + 'vw; ' +
                  'top: ' + (bx.top/h * 100) + 'vh;');
              $('#video').removeClass('hideMe');      /* show video */
              renderReactPlayer(container, {url: pt.customdata, playing: true});
        }
    });
    el.on('plotly_unhover', function(d) {  /* collapse image when tooltip collapses */
        tooltip.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style('opacity', 0);
    });
    el.on('plotly_doubleclick', function(d) {  /* collapse image when container collapses */
        renderReactPlayer($('#video')[0], {url: pt.customdata, playing: false});  /* stop video */
        $('#video').addClass('hideMe');        /* hide video */
    });
}"
```

Let me know if you've questions or find any new issues.

---

---

##### Update

While my reasoning and explanations in my original answer hold true, I've written a consolidated version of what was your two different `onRender` calls. The criteria that distinguish whether you have a video or an image is `curveNumber`, you can think of this as per trace. For example, if you called the map first and the points second, this wouldn't work correctly. (You would have to switch the criteria `pt.curveNumber === 0` vs `pt.curveNumber === 1`.)

Here's the code and the call for the plot.

```
jsC <- "
function(el) {
    var tooltip = d3.select('#' + el.id + ' .svg-container')  /* identify container */
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'my-custom-tooltip');
    $('head').append('<style>iframe[id^=\"widget\"] { width: 100%; } </style>');
    var container = document.getElementById('video');

    el.on('plotly_hover', function(d) {         /* add content on hover */ 
        pt = d.points[0];
        var h = window.innerHeight;             /* get viewers screen size */
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        bx = document.querySelector('div.mapboxgl-map').getBoundingClientRect();

        if(pt.curveNumber === 0) {              /* you have an image; first trace */
                  /* if hovering on point that contains an image, halt/hide video - playing */
            if($('[id^=widget]').length) {
                renderReactPlayer($('#video')[0], {url: pt.customdata, playing: false});  /* stop video */
                $('[id^=widget]').css('opacity', 0);  /* hide video */
            }
            img = '<img src=\\\'' +  pt.customdata + '\\\' width=100>';  /* image in hover */ 
                        /* the position of the map on the webpage */ 
            tooltip.html(img)             /* calculate % left/right map to screen position */
                .style('position', 'absolute')
                .style('left', (bx.left/w * 100) + 'vw')
                .style('top', (bx.top/h * 100) + 'vh');
            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(300)
                .style('opacity', 1);


        } else if (pt.curveNumber === 1) {     /* you have a video; second trace */
              container.setAttribute(     /* calculate % left/right map to screen position */
                  'style',
                  'position: absolute; left:' + (bx.left/w * 100) + 'vw; ' +
                  'top: ' + (bx.top/h * 100) + 'vh;');
              $('[id^=widget]').css('opacity', 1);  /* opac = 0 stop video; opac = 1 play */
              renderReactPlayer(container, {url: pt.customdata, playing: true});
        }
    });
    el.on('plotly_unhover', function(d) {  /* collapse image when tooltip collapses */
        tooltip.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style('opacity', 0);
    });
    el.on('plotly_doubleclick', function(d) {  /* collapse image when container collapses */
        renderReactPlayer($('#video')[0], {url: pt.customdata, playing: false});  /* stop video */
        $('[id^=widget]').css('opacity', 0);  /* hide video */
    });
}"
```

Then just swap out the two `onRender` calls for the one.

```
p <- plot_ly(df, lon = ~x, lat = ~y, type = "scattermapbox", mode = "markers", 
             hoverinfo = ~x, customdata = ~url) %>%
  add_trace(data = df, lon = ~x + 0.1, lat = ~y, type = "scattermapbox", 
            mode = "markers", hoverinfo = ~x, 
            customdata = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ab_channel=RickAstley") %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                       center = list(lon = -81 ,lat= 44),
                       layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                          source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) %>%
  # onRender(js2) %>%
  # onRender(js3)
  # onRender(js3N) %>% 
  onRender(jsC) %>%            #<---- I'm new!!
  config(doubleClickDelay = 1500)
```

Let me know if you run into any issues with this.

---

---

##### Originally Wrote

Answers:

*How do I make the on-click video only work for trace 2? So clicking on trace 1 doesn't do anything?*

You have 3 markers for trace 0 and 3 for trace 1. For trace 0, you provided 3 strings for the 3 markers. For trace 1, you provided one string for 3 markers. If you only wanted the 2nd marker to present the video, modify the parameter: `customdata = c('', url, '')`

*How do I make the video smaller and show up within the map area, as opposed to below the map?*

A few things have to happen.

- Do you still want it centered? (You called for `align = 'center'` when you created the video element.) I am going to assume that you would rather have it in the same position as your images. In my modifications to what was the object `js3`, I use the `window.innerHeight` and etc. as in `js2`. If you wanted it in a different position, you can change the values set for `left`, and `top` in the code I will provide.
- What size do you want the video to be? In the new version of what was `js3`, you'll see the creation of a `<style>` element. In this element, I've set the width to 100%. You can change this value as you please. In the code, it looks like this:

`$('head').append('<style>iframe[id^=\"widget\"] { width: 100%; } </style>');`

It will continue to maintain the aspect ratio, so only width adjustments are necessary. However, you could end up with some ugly padding when you shrink the video. You can always add a height call that matches the width if you get a bunch of padding. For example:

`$('head').append('<style>iframe[id^=\"widget\"] { width: 50%; height: 50%} </style>');`

To change size and position you'll need to modify the objects `js3` and `video`. I'm going to come back to this after addressing your other inquiries.

*How do I make the video close-able? Currently, I can't make it go away unless I click on trace 1 4*

I've added a `plotly_doubleclick` to close the video.

When I use this functionality I can't click my mouse fast enough to appease Plotly most of the time, so I've also added `config(doubleClickDelay = 1500)` so that there is no issue with the speed in which I double-click. You'll see this function call added to the object `p`.

*The map seems to no longer be zoomable after this exercise...*
I wasn't able to duplicate this issue. Let me know if, after these changes, it still doesn't work for you.

```
# replacement of `js3`, most mods are taken from `js2`
js3N <- "function(el) {
            $('head').append('<style>iframe[id^=\"widget\"] { width: 100%; } </style>');
            var container = document.getElementById('video');
            el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
                url = d.points[0].customdata;             /* changed to global (removed var) */
                var h = window.innerHeight;
                var w = window.innerWidth;
                container.setAttribute(     /* calculate % left/right map to screen position */
                  'style',
                  'position: absolute; left:' + (bx.left/w * 100) + 'vw; ' +
                  'top: ' + (bx.top/h * 100) + 'vh;');
                $('[id^=widget]').css('opacity', 1);  /* opac = 0 stop video; opac = 1 play */
                renderReactPlayer(container, {url: url, playing: true});
            })
            el.on('plotly_doubleclick', function(d) {  /* collapse image when container collapses */
                renderReactPlayer($('#video')[0], {url: url, playing: false});  /* stop video */
                $('[id^=widget]').css('opacity', 0);  /* hide video */
            });
        }" 

# replacement of `video` -- removed align = "center"
video <- tags$div(id = "video")

# replacement of `p`, the ONLY changes after `onRender(js2)`
p <- plot_ly(df, lon = ~x, lat = ~y, type = "scattermapbox", mode = "markers", 
             hoverinfo = ~x, customdata = ~url) %>%
  add_trace(data = df, lon = ~x + 0.1, lat = ~y, type = "scattermapbox", 
            mode = "markers", hoverinfo = ~x, 
            customdata = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ab_channel=RickAstley"
            ) %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                       center = list(lon = -81 ,lat= 44),
                       layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                          source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) %>%
  onRender(js2) %>%
  # onRender(js3)
  onRender(js3N) %>% config(doubleClickDelay = 1500)    #<---- I'm new!!
```

[image]

Here's what it looks like if you change it to 50% with
`$('head').append('<style>iframe[id^=\"widget\"] { width: 50%; height: 50%} </style>');`

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the radio silence. It's very odd - when I put everything together, the video part just displays as a broken link. And I'm obviously way out of my depth to figure out where I'm going wrong. I edited my answer to provide a "everything together" piece of code. If you're up for taking a look, thank would be amazing!

Comment: Have you tried clicking on it, instead of hovering? I do see the broken icon when I hover, but it plays the video when I click. I'm going to look into the code to see why you're getting that icon, though. Let me know if clicking works for you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything at all when I click on it (running the full code from the edit to my question)... So it still just shows the broken link of an image whether I hover or click...

Comment: It should come up when hovering with the new `jsC`.  If you're still having an issue getting the video to play, will you please try a different URL and see if that works? When I initially worked on this question the URL you gave me didn't work. However, I could put it in my browser directly and it worked just fine. The URL you provided is working just fine for me right now, but that is pretty odd, ya know?

Comment: God, I'm glad you mentioned trying a different video. So with a new link, it does open, but on hover (as opposed to click). The video does close when I double-click the map (is that correct?), but then the map stops being responsive - no zooming, on-hover, or anything else available.... Any thoughts?

Comment: Is that with/without the new code I added to my answer? In RStudio? Your browser? Both? Which browser(s) are you using? Do you still see the menu on the top right when your mouse is over the plot? What method are you using to zoom? Mouse scroll? Configuration button? (That's in that menu top right.) I haven't been able to replicate this problem.

Comment: How odd. Yes, I had incorporated the new code from your updated answer. Now - I was originally running the code in an `Rmd` file, knitting it into html. The behaviour (on-hover video and nonresponsive map after) was happening in both RStudio and in the html file (Edge and Chrome). I use a mouse scroll to zoom, and the menu still shows and is responsive. When I run just the code in RStudio, without knitting, the behaviour is the same. When I run just the code in R GUI and it opens the map in Edge, the video opens on-hover, but the map stays responsive after the double-click to close.

Comment: Are you using `browsable` in RMD? How are you calling this within RMD?

Comment: I... was. Is that not kosher? I added the full code to the question now. But it's literally everything we've discussed, just wrapped in ` ```{r, warning=FALSE, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE} ` and ` ``` `.

Comment: I'm just trying to reproduce the error.  What do you have the output set to in your YAML?

Comment: I've added an update to my answer. I finally replicated the problem...well, I think I had the problem the whole time, but didn't realize it, because I had made the map large and the video small... either way, this should resolve the issues regarding zoom. Additionally, you can test whether the video will play like this (if it returns  1: won't play; 0: plays )   `system(paste0("curl -s ", url, " | grep \"UNPLAYABLE\" | wc -l"), intern = T)` ...replace `url` with the URL you want to check.